# Google Places API library use without map - javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I need to get the closest establishments in 100m radius from specific coordinates.
I found the Google Places API sample code, but I don't use a map in my application, since this results will be rendered in a list.
Here is the API code:

```
var map;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    types: ['store']
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Someone here has found that you can use a node to render the attribution into,
but when I try ti render in it:

```
var $attrib = $('<div id="attributions"></div>');
$('#main').append($attrib);
...
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($attrib);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: this.j[Wb] is not a function
```

from somewhere deep inside the API library.
I hope this is enough of information to figure the problem out

Comment: What does the code that causes the problem look like? Please a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$attrib` probably is not a Node, I guess it's a jQuery-object.

Use

```
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($attrib[0]);
```

or without jQuery:

```
service = new google.maps.places
          .PlacesService(document.getElementById('main')
                         .appendChild(document.createElement('div')));
```

Comment: Dr. Molle, thank you, it worked! Could you explain what is node in this case?

Comment: Node is a HTML-element, in this case the `div#attributions` which has been created via jQuery. But jQuery doesn't return a HTML-element, it returns a jQuery-object(which includes an array with the  HTML-elements). To get a single HTML-element out of this array access it via the index(starting with 0). There is only a single element in the array, so `$attrib[0]` will point to this element.